# Trying to understand Exit, Loop, Method and If and Else

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, methods, exit

I am trying to understand how to use the method, loop,if-else statement, and exit code. So I'm writing a simple calculation base on the user choice but I can't figure out how to make the input read to loop back when user input else than the number *(mean no alphabet are allowed)* and it will continue back to the option till the user enter the right option that is either 1 or 2.

Have I made a mistake, or is there a way to simplify this code?

I WANT OUTPUT TO BE LIKE THIS:

> ```
> [1] Calculation 
> [2] Exit
> Your choice: a
>
> Please choose only 1 or 2
>
> [1] Calculation 
> [2] Exit
> Your choice: 1
>
> Enter 1st number: 1 
> Enter 2nd number: 1 
> Total: 2
> ```

CODE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Testing {
    
        int ans;
        boolean Loop = true;
    
        public void SimpleCalculation() {
    
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            while (Loop) {
                System.out.println("[1] Calculation ");
                System.out.println("[2] Exit");
                System.out.print("Your choice: ");
                ans = input.nextInt();
    
                if (ans == 1) {
                    System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
                    int number1 = input.nextInt();
    
                    System.out.print("Enter 2nd number: ");
                    int number2 = input.nextInt();
                    
                    int result = number1 + number2;
                    System.out.println("Total: " + result);
    
                } else if (ans == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Thank you");
                    input.close();
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please choose only 1 or 2");
                }
            }
             System.exit (0);
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            Testing t = new Testing();
            t.SimpleCalculation();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hum, I made some simple utility functions for input like this, but then it would be an overkill for your problem. This problem is simple enough for you to solve on your own, here's a simple tutorial to help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-class-in-java/#:~:text=Scanner%20is%20a%20class%20in,and%20strings.&text=next()%20function%20returns%20the,first%20character%20in%20that%20string.

Comment: [Scanner.hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) tells  you if the input is an integer or not. If it returns false, you can ask the user to reenter it.

Comment: Scanner.hasNextInt never heard of it

Comment: but thank you let me try first @user

Comment: ahh, where am I suppose to put it cause if I put it in the if-else condition statement it gives me errors and when I put in at else it didn't read and when I put it in the while loop condition it doesn't show anything? @user

Comment: See [Anish B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64033798/11882002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code :

```
public class Testing {

    public static void SimpleCalculation() {
        boolean Loop = true;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (Loop) {
            System.out.println("[1] Calculation ");
            System.out.println("[2] Exit");
            System.out.print("Your choice: ");
            while(!input.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Please choose only 1 or 2");
                input.nextLine();
                continue;
            }
            int ans = input.nextInt();

            if (ans == 1) {
                System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
                int number1 = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter 2nd number: ");
                int number2 = input.nextInt();
                
                int result = number1 + number2;
                System.out.println("Total: " + result);
            } else if (ans == 2) {
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                input.close();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please choose only 1 or 2");
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleCalculation();
    }

}
```

Output :

```
[1] Calculation 
[2] Exit
Your choice: a
Please choose only 1 or 2
[1] Calculation 
[2] Exit
Your choice: 1
Enter 1st number: 1
Enter 2nd number: 2
Total: 3
```

Comment: Yes it work thank you but may i ask why can't i put it at the bottom at the else @Anish